# How do I configure a VLAN interface to start at boot?

Tags: settings, networking

I successfully used the [Ubuntu Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan) to configure a VLAN interface manually, but I want this to take place at boot. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

- `sudo apt-get install vlan`
- `sudo su -c 'echo "8021q" >> /etc/modules'`
- `sudo su -c 'echo "source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*" >> /etc/network/interfaces'`
- Create a new file in directory `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` e.g.`vlan10` with the following contents:

> auto enp3s0.10
>   iface enp3s0.10 inet dhcp
>    vlan-raw-device enp3s0

* The actual device name, `enp3s0` in this case, will vary depending on your network driver